# Add historical data for key field in separate column (previous contract)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate how many days it takes for customers to change between certain contracts. This can go instantaneous or take many days, and I want to filter the cases that take too long.

Currently I have a dataset with customers (AccountNum), contracts (ContractId), the buildings they live(d) in (RentalObjectId). An AccountNum can switch ContractId's and AccountNums can start a new ContractId in a RentalObjectId another AccountNum lived before. So the data looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE PMCCONTRACT (
AccountNum nvarchar(20),
ContractId nvarchar(20),
RentalObjectId nvarchar(20),
ValidFrom date,
ValidTo date);

INSERT INTO PMCCONTRACT (AccountNum, ContractId, RentalObjectId, ValidFrom, ValidTo)
VALUES
('1','HC1','1','43101','43221'),
('2','HC2','2','43101','43252'),
('3','HC3','3','43466','NULL'),
('1','HC4','2','43222','NULL'),
('2','HC5','4','43261','43466'),
('4','HC6','5','43525','NULL');
```

And this is how I want it to look like:

```
CREATE TABLE PMCCONTRACTFIX (
AccountNum nvarchar(20),
ContractId nvarchar(20),
RentalObjectId nvarchar(20),
ValidFrom date,
ValidTo date,
PreviousContract nvarchar(20),
PreviousContractValidTo date,
DaysBetweenContracts int);

INSERT INTO PMCCONTRACTFIX (AccountNum, ContractId, RentalObjectId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, PreviousContract, PreviousContractValidTo, DaysBetweenContracts)
VALUES
('1','HC1','1','43101','43221','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
('2','HC2','2','43101','43252','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
('3','HC3','3','43466','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'),
('1','HC4','2','43222','NULL','HC1','43221','1'),
('2','HC5','4','43261','43466','HC2','43252','9'),
('4','HC6','5','43525','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL');
```

I don't know how to start solving this issue. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Kind regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

you can set trigger on `PMCCONTRACTFIX` and handle the `Previous` Columns 
this code can give you some idea :

```
update p
set PreviousContract=P2.ContractId  , PreviousContractValidTo=p2.ValidTo,DaysBetweenContracts=(P2.ValidFrom-P2.ValidTo)
from PMCCONTRACTFIX P
               left join PMCCONTRACTFIX P2 on p.AccountNum=p2.AccountNum
               left join (select AccountNum,MAx(ContractId) ContractId from PMCCONTRACTFIX  Group by AccountNum ) X on X.ContractId = P2.ContractId
```

but remember you can't use this on an after trigger

```
Select p. *,P2.ContractId  , p2.ValidTo,(P2.ValidFrom-P2.ValidTo)
from PMCCONTRACTFIX P
               left join PMCCONTRACTFIX P2 on p.AccountNum=p2.AccountNum
               left join (select AccountNum,MAx(ContractId) ContractId from PMCCONTRACTFIX  Group by AccountNum ) X on X.ContractId = P2.ContractId
```

Comment: The thing is that PMCCONTRACTFIX is not a table that exists in my DB. It's how I want the end result to look like, based solely on the table PMCCONTRACT.

Comment: You can use that to create a view

Answer (score 0):

If account can have only one active contract, you can employ a traditional effective date type structure.

So your plan is accnum and effective date.  If someone switches contract, you don't update anything, instead add a row for that effective date.

Now if you want to go back to see the world on any date, you simply find the record that was effective, i.e. where effective date in table <= your desired date.

Since you would have a need to also see current records, create a view that filters record using database current date function.

You will not even need a to date.  Instead have a column To indicate that contract is terminated.  So you would add a record indicating the date that contract is terminated.  Create the table as follows

```
table name = PMCCONTRACT

PK {AccountNum, ContractId, effdte [This is a date column]}
RentalContractId
enabled?
```

Now you only add rows to the table.  You never update.  Whenever you are looking up data you are looking data "as of a certain data" and that as of can be assumed as today.  So your sql to get data will be:

```
input = checkEffDte, e.g. today, AccountNum, ContractId

select *
from PMCCONTRACT c1
where c1.AccountNum = :AccountNum
and c1.ContractId = :ContractId
and c1.effdte = ( select max(effdte)
                  from PMCCONTRACT c2
                  where c2.AccountNum = c1.AccountNum
                  and c2.ContractId = c1.ContractId
                  and c2.effdte <= :checkEffDte
                )
```

So you can see what the rentalContract was on any given date.  You are finding the max record BEFORE the effective date.

You can turn above into a view as well - then you will have a quick way to see current records for all.

Comment: Actually AccountNum's can have multiple contracts. I just realized that Accountnum in combination with Contract will be the only way to have it unique in my current setup. Other than that I have to be honest I don't really understand what you mean. When I google 'traditional effective date type structure SQL', I didn't find anything  useful